# Supporting Folder Structure with Realm

Tags: android, realm

I am interested in representing folder system using RealmDB:

My first thought was:

```
 public class FolderItem extends RealmObject {
    public String name;
 }

 public class Folder extends FolderItem {
     public ArrayList<FolderItem> folderItems;
 }

 public  class File extends FolderItem {
    public String path;
 }
```

I am now seeing an error that Folder saying Annotated class Folder must extend a Realm class ... Does this mean recursive structures like this don't work or that inheritance is not fully supported? Or does anyone have better idea on how to do this?

Comment: I think realm does not support inheritance. This might help you https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/761

Comment: Inheritance is not supported. Only interfaces are. You could always use the same table and just have a string type to specify if it's a folder or a file.

Comment: Until Inheritence is supported you can use composition instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance

Comment: Well now the problem is I am getting using composition is that ArrayList<FileItem> elements is not supported within FileItem as a type ...

Comment: I have another question on doing this with composition so I can have levels?

Answer (score 0):

If folders only contain files and other folders, you could easily represent it without needing inheritance:

```
 public class File {
    public String name;
 }

 public class Folder {
     public String name;
     public ArrayList<File>   files;
     public ArrayList<Folder> folders;
 }
```